# Angular 15 breaks react lib import

Tags: angular, webpack, react-grid-layout

I am using some not published react library (X) inside of Angular application.That library X is using react-grid-layout library like this

```
var _reactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');

require('react-grid-layout/css/styles.css');
```

build fails with error

```
./node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css?ngGlobalStyle:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .react-grid-layout {
|   position: relative;
|   transition: height 200ms ease;
× Failed to compile.
```

With angular version 14.1 this was working normally, when I upgraded package versions to 15.2.4 this started to happen.react-grid-layout/css/styles/css is added in angular.json.

Is there way to fix this, without changing library X code?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnlTt.png)

Tried with adding library css files and react-grid-layout css file in angular.json, not working.